# Microsoft Graph API: Access a drive that is not in the "root drive"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint site where there is a `drive` that is not the default `drive` (Shared Documents). How do I access this drive?

Normally to access a file that would be `mysite.com/Shared Documents/folder`, I would do the following get the site id:

```
GET /v1.0/sites/{sharepoint.mycompany.com}:/sites/{mySite}:/
```

I could then retrieve the default drive using:

```
GET /v1.0/sites/{mySiteId}/drive
```

In this case, my fail is not in the default drive. How do I access a different drive?

Answer (score 1):

You need to address the [`/drives`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/site?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships) collection rather than the default `/drive`. You can retrieve the list of Drives that belong to a site by calling:

```
GET /v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drives?select=id,name
```

This will return a collection of `drive` resources:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "id1",
            "name": "Documents"
        },
        {
            "id": "id2",
            "name": "Other Documents"
        }

    ]
}
```

You can then address the [`drive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/drive?view=graph-rest-1.0) by `id` like this:

```
GET /v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drives/{driveId}
```